# Need to determine if a row in a dataset meets the parameter of acceptable or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In one table I have parameters. This represents the number of instances for Requested and provides the allowable number of Missed for those instances e.g. if 11 requests have been received and 1 was missed then this is allowable, if 11 requests have been received and 2 were missed this is not allowable.

In the next table is the data than needs to be assess to see if it is allowable (Yes) or not (No).  I have tried a few different `IF` and `AND` formulas, but can only seem to get the data to either assess against the first row of the parameters.

[image]

Comment: It's simple,, you have to test both in Table 2 like =IF(and(B2>=11,C2>=1),"Yes","No") ,,, U get Yes in D3:D11 since both values in Col B & Col C are >11 and >1 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF([@Requested]>=INDEX(Table1[Requested Base],MATCH([@Missed],Table1[Missed Allowable],0)),"Yes","No"),"No")
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, makes assessing the 10K data set much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XLOOKUP to find the correct row in Table1 for each row in Table2, and return the Missed Allowable from Table1, which you can then directly compare to the Missed column in Table2 to determine whether too many were missed or not.

Something like this:

```
=[@Missed]>XLOOKUP([@Requested],Table1[Requested Base],Table1[Missed Allowable],0,-1)
```

[image]